# GCP Dataform - Can't connect repository to Github via SSH

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, ssh, dataform

I have a working ssh key and when I try to connect Dataform to Github with it, I get the error "We are unable to connect to your Git provider with the configured credentials". There's no other information about the error. If there is, I'm not sure where to look.

What I've done so far:

1. Created a secret in GCP with the file selection left empty, and set the secret value as the private ssh key like the following:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
private_key
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

2. Bound the secret to Dataform repository, and set the "Host public key" value as the following:

```
ssh-ed25519 public_key comment
```

I verified that there's no typo in the values I entered. Am I missing something here? Could it be wrong key format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, the issue was that I was supplying the public key of the [GitHub deploy key](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys) I generated for my target repository, not the [GitHub SSH key fingerprint](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints):

```
github.com ssh-rsa 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
```

The documentation asks for this value in `ALGORITHM BASE64_KEY_VALUE` format, so I successfully configured the connection with

```
ssh-rsa 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
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error message, you may want to check the permissions on the private key as it needs to be readable by the Dataform process and verify that it matches the entry on your secret. The public key should also be in place on your GitHub account while the private key should be used for the authentication. Also, it never hurts to check your network and security settings such as firewalls for good measure. Attached is a document that can help your use case.[1]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/connect-repository

Comment: I don't think the issue is the SSH key itself, as I can clone and make changes in a private repo with it. I've followed the instructions in the link you provided, but it's still not working. It says to "create a secret with the private SSH key as the secret value", which I did, and to "enter a single public host key of your Git provider in the SSH public host key value field", which I also did. Also I can confirm that my Dataform project has all the required permissions to access secrets because it successfully connects using a Github PAT from secrets. SSH connection however, doesn't work.